# Error de conexión a BBDD sql-server ODBC Error

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, ftp, odbc

Hola tengo un  problema que creo que es bastante simple pero que no doy con él.
Tengo una mini aplicación subida a la nube de **AZURE** que he subido por **FTP**.
mi aplicación desde local funciona correctamente pero desde la nube intento establecer una conexión a la **BBDD** de sqlserver y tengo este error:
**

```
[code] => -49
            [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server
```

**
la conexión en mi local funciona perfectamente

> $compr= sqlsrv_connect($conn);
>   esto me devuelve true en mi local, pero en la nube cuando me meto al dominio correspondiente me casca y me pone lo de ODBC.

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano ? 
Lo agradecería bastante.
Un saludo

Comment: Es tema de Driver, en tu máquina local tienes el driver sqlsrv y en Azure no lo tiene instalado en el servidor, solamente tiene ODBC. Una de dos, instala el driver sqlsrv en Azure o tanto como tu máquina y la nube trabaja con ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

Es lo que te comenta @otacon070. Otra posibilidad es crear un fichero info.php en ambos servidores con una llamada a la función phpinfo() y puedas ver las diferencias que tienes en ambos servidores.